# SOAP, REST or plain HTTP POST for sending file and other data to different domain?

Tags: rest, post, soap, service, web

I am in the process of creating and negotiating a specification for some new functionality on a web app. The new functionality includes enabling users to send PDF files along with some other data (a name, a creation date, a city, etc.) to a server on a different domain. So it is really multipart data, binary and plain text mixed together.

What would be your preferred way of doing this, knowing that

- the PDF files will not exceed 5 MB and the plain text data fields are very small
- our development time is limited to about 10 days

The developer of the receiving application is in favour of SOAP (not sure if he wants to encode the file or send it as an attachment), because it is tried and tested in their application. I think I am in favour of using just plain POST, because it's simple and doesn't require additional protocols. My argument against SOAP would be that our app is written in Java and theirs in .NET and I don't want to run into compatibility issues with SOAP.

I have little experience with web services, so any arguments against or in favour of these technologies will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are being downvoted is that you have shown little to no effort.

There are no compatibility issues with java to .NET for the most part.  Additionally if your vendor(developer) has proven success with a method then why are you going to spend money developing an entirely separate solution which will have to be maintained specifically for you.

It sounds like you are just spewing rhetoric because you wish to win an argument rather than be correct.

Comment: Instead of telling me I am spewing rhetoric you could have elaborated a bit on 'the most part' bit of your remark on java en .NET compatibility. That would have been helpful. I am not trying to win an argument by the way. I need the best choice and SOAP is definitely one of the options.